# How can I add a background image while combining *.png files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, imagemagick-convert

I'd like to add a background image while combining *.png files to make an mp4 file, using ffmpeg.

Currently, I have to first create an animated gif using imagemagick convert, like this:

```
convert -delay ${DELAY} -dispose Background *.png -coalesce null: ${BACKGROUND} -compose dstOver -layers composite -layers optimize -loop 0 planet.gif
```

Then I process that animated gif using ffmpeg to optimize it:

```
ffmpeg -i planet.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" planet.mp4
```

Which sort of works, but is slow and has a problem. I craps out if I go above about 100 input files, and creates animated gifs that are basically just white screens.

ffmpeg alone works great, and 100 times faster stitching the *.png files together

ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" planet.mp4

But, no background there. I haven't found anyway to add that background. Does ffmpeg even support such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

using scale2ref, overlay

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' \
-loop 1 -framerate 10 -i bg.png -filter_complex "
[0]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[v0];
[1][v0]scale2ref[v1][v0];
[v1]setsar=1[v1];
[v1][v0]overlay=shortest=1
" -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4 -y
```